# How to perform count and select in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, go-gorm

So in a blog application I am building, I have two tables:

```
// Post model
type Post struct {
   Id      int    `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
   OwnerId int    `json:"owner_id" // foreign key to User model
   Title   string `json:"title"`
   Body    string `json:"body"`
   Likes   []Like `json:"likes"`
}
```

```
// Like model
type Like struct {
   PostId  int `json:"post_id"`  // foreign key to Post model
   LikerId int `json:"liker_id"` // foreign key to User model
}
```

**I want to run a query which gets posts made by a user as well as whether the current user liked the post(s) and the total number of likes on each post**. I'd like to do all of this in a single query because splitting this into multiple queries will be bad for performance when a user has multiple posts which is most likely the case.

I constructed this query but I get an incorrect syntax error which I totally expected:

```
SELECT post.title, post.body, COUNT(likes), lk.liker_id
FROM posts as post
LEFT JOIN likes
ON post.owner_id = "..." AND likes.post_id = post.id
LEFT JOIN likes as lk
ON lk.post_id = post.id AND lk.liker_id = "current_user_id"
```

How could I accomplish this? Thank you!

**EDIT: here are the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the posts and likes models:**

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE posts;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| posts | CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` longtext,
  `body` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_users_posts` (`owner_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_posts` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE likes;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| likes | CREATE TABLE `likes` (
  `post_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `liker_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `fk_likes_liker` (`liker_id`),
  KEY `fk_posts_likes` (`post_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_likes_liker` FOREIGN KEY (`liker_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_posts_likes` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Since you've tagged `mysql`, please provide the mysql table definition code. `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts; SHOW CREATE TABLE likes;` For further information see also [ask] and how to create a [example]

Comment: I agree with @PinkeHelga but you're going to need a `GROUP BY` because of the aggregate function `COUNT`.

Comment: Adding to the above, please show sample data, and sample output  To me it seems a bit strange to select rows from the likes table and show the count at the same time.  Normally, you would have one or the other.

Comment: Inadequate indexes; see [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: @RickJames The relationship I setup between posts and likes is a one-to-many where one post has many likes. Is this wrong? Should it be a many-to-many relationship? If so, why?

Comment: @darkstar - Can't one "liker" like many different "posts" _and_ many different "likers" can like one "post"?  That's what your table `likes` implies.  That is "many-to-many".

Comment: The post-to-likes is a one-to-many. The post-to-likers is many-to-many through likes.

Comment: Change `COUNT(likes)` to `COUNT(*)`, and add a `GROUP BY post.id` as suggested above.

Comment: @Jared I made some changes and now the `posts` and `likes` table have a many-to-many relationship where the join table holds the `post_id` and `liker_id(user_id)`. Is this fine? I will take a look at `group by` next.

Comment: Ehm. There are 3 entities there: posts, likes and users. And the relationships as follows: users-to-posts as one-to-many (one user is an author for many posts), posts-to-likes as one-to-many (one post has many likes), users-to-likes as one-to-many (one user has many likes). And at last the users-to-posts as many-to-many that is somewhat indirect relationship that does not need explicit definition, cause it just appears from the posts-to-likes and user-to-likes naturally. FK definitions in your question are just fine. All you needed was a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: And add a `PRIMARY KEY(post_id, liker_id)` for the likes table, and you're done.